# Servlet configurado com anotações não é carregado

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class SpringServlet extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebAppConfiguration.class,JPAConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Meu servlet não é carregado quando subo a aplicação, me retornando Erro 404. Alguem tem idéia do motivo? No meu log não acusa erro nenhum.
Usava Spring com xml e estou tentando aprender a usar com anotações.

Estou usando Tomcat7.

Comment: aonde está a anotação ?

Comment: @CristianUrbainski qual anotação? Estou seguindo exemplos de um livro e as classes anotadas sao WebAppConifguration e JPAConfiguration. Na classe do servlet não existe nenhuma anotação. Assim que possível edito a questão adicionado o código de WebAppConfiguration e JPAConfiguration